# How do I use or implement the interfaces in Win32's shobjidl_core.h?

Tags: c++, winapi, abstract-class

I am trying to instantiate [IDesktopWallpaper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper) to access some of its functions, but they are all pure virtual voids. Because of this the compiler throws an error when I try to do this. The specific methods I'm trying to use are [`GetMonitorDevicePathAt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper-getmonitordevicepathat) and [`GetWallpaper()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper-getwallpaper).

Are there other headers I have to include, or libraries that I should link? Or are there other methods that achieve the same?

Comment: [Obtaining information about the user's wallpaper on multiple monitors](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140602-00/?p=833).

Comment: You cannot instantiate an interface, you have to instantiate an object (class) which implements that interface. See comment above from @IInspectable `CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DesktopWallpaper, nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL,
                  IID_PPV_ARGS(&spdw));`

Comment: I see. Thanks to both of you for your responses

Answer (score 3):

[`IDesktopWallpaper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper) is a [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model) interface. It is a language-agnostic description of a programming interface. In C++ this gets commonly mapped to a struct that consists of purely virtual functions exclusively. This conveniently prevents accidental instantiation of the interface type.

To use any given COM interface one has to instantiate a COM *object* that implements that interface. COM provides a standard factory method to do so: [`CoCreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance). The following snippet illustrates how to use it:

```cpp
IDesktopWallpaper* pWallpaper { nullptr };
auto hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DesktopWallpaper, nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL,
                             IID_IDesktopWallpaper, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&pWallpaper));
```

This requests COM to search its object registry for a COM object with class ID `CLSID_DesktopWallpaper`, attempt to instantiate it, and on success return a valid interface pointer identified by `IID_IDesktopWallpaper`. At this point the `IDesktopWallpaper` API is available to clients through the `pWallpaper` pointer.

---

That's not all, though. COM has a few requirements that the previous snippet ignored. At a bare minimum, the following need to be implemented:

- To use COM on a thread the COM library needs to be initialized to use it. Use [CoInitialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-coinitialize), or [CoInitializeEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex) if you have special requirements.
- Every successful call to `CoCreateInstance`, [`AddRef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-addref), and [`QueryInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-queryinterface(refiid_void)) must be matched with a call to [`Release`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-release) to properly manage object lifetimes.
- Each successful COM initialization call must be matched with a call to [`CoUninitialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-couninitialize) (though I'm no longer sure, whether this [should actually happen](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues/1169#issuecomment-926877227)). If you do make sure [you know when your destructors run](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040520-00/?p=39243).

The following quality-of-life improvements are highly recommended, especially when using C++. None of them are strictly required, though:

- The final two arguments to `CoCreateInstace` are related. Both interface pointer type and interface ID must agree. The [`IID_PPV_ARGS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-iid_ppv_args) macro derives both from a single input, making sure that mismatches won't happen.
- COM interfaces are reference counted, and clients need to report when they require another reference, as well as when they are done using one. Smart pointer libraries are a convenient tool to make the manual process automatic.
- Errors in COM are primarily reported by way of return values, encoded as [`HRESULT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/0642cb2f-2075-4469-918c-4441e69c548a)s. With historic evidence over more than half of a century it has come apparent: Ignoring return values is as convenient as it is common. C++ exceptions cannot. Use them, unless there is a convincing reason not to (e.g. when implementing library code).
- Use of C++ exceptions frees a function's return value channel, opening up the opportunity for a much more natural interface design.

---

With the fundamentals out of the way, it's time to derive an implementation. The following will be using C++ exceptions for error reporting, which pretty much requires application of the [RAII idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) throughout. The COM smart pointer library for today is going to be Microsoft's [`_com_ptr_t`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-ptr-t-class), with [`_com_error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-error-class) as the error reporting base class.

The implementation makes use of the undocumented `_com_util::CheckError` function, that translates between `HRESULT` values and C++ exceptions.

```cpp
#include <ShObjIdl_core.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <comip.h>
#include <comutil.h>

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

// Declares a concrete _com_ptr_t instantiation for IDesktopWallpaper
// called IDesktopWallpaperPtr
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IDesktopWallpaper, __uuidof(IDesktopWallpaper));

using _com_util::CheckError;
```

`ComInit`:

```cpp
struct ComInit
{
    ComInit() { CheckError(::CoInitialize(nullptr)); }
    ~ComInit() noexcept { ::CoUninitialize(); }
};
```

This structure is used to initialize and uninitialize the COM library on the calling thread. If initialization fails, the c'tor throws an exception and the d'tor never runs. Otherwise the d'tor always runs when the object goes out of scope. It does so during stack unwinding when handling exceptions as well.

`GetMonitorDevicePathCount` wrapper:

```cpp
[[nodiscard]]
uint32_t GetMonitorDevicePathCount(IDesktopWallpaper* pWallpaper) {
    uint32_t count {};
    CheckError(pWallpaper->GetMonitorDevicePathCount(&count));
    return count;
}
```

This follows a recurring theme, that's used for the other wrapper implementations as well: It calls into the supplied interface, translates error return values into C++ exceptions, and promotes the out-parameter to the actual return value.

`GetMonitorDevicePathAt` and `GetWallpaper` wrappers:

```cpp
[[nodiscard]]
std::wstring GetMonitorDevicePathAt(IDesktopWallpaper* pWallpaper, uint32_t index) {
    wchar_t* p { nullptr };
    CheckError(pWallpaper->GetMonitorDevicePathAt(index, &p));
    if (p) {
        auto deleter = [](void* p) noexcept { ::CoTaskMemFree(p); };
        std::unique_ptr<wchar_t, decltype(deleter)> cleaner { p, deleter };
        return { p };
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}

[[nodiscard]]
std::wstring GetWallpaper(IDesktopWallpaper* pWallpaper, std::wstring_view dev_path) {
    wchar_t* p { nullptr };
    CheckError(pWallpaper->GetWallpaper(dev_path.data(), &p));
    if (p) {
        auto deleter = [](void* p) noexcept { ::CoTaskMemFree(p); };
        std::unique_ptr<wchar_t, decltype(deleter)> cleaner { p, deleter };
        return { p };
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

These functions are doing the same translations as before, though this time around things are a bit more subtle. Either interface method allocates memory and transfers responsibility to the caller. Neither aspect is documented, so we're left [to guess](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130923-00/?p=3163).

That's subtle, but that's not all. With either function constructing a new `std::wstring` object on return, and the possibility of that c'tor failing with an exception, we need to make sure that memory gets freed even when leaving the function by way of a C++ exception. That's what the seemingly unused `cleaner` object does. It re-purposes a `std::unique_ptr` solely for its ability to run a custom deleter on destruction, so that `CoTaskMemFree` always gets called before returning.

The `if (p)` conditional here is also required. While the behavior of passing a null pointer into `CoTaskMemFree` is well defined, constructing a `std::wstring` from a null pointer is not.

With all that done it is now time to write a program that puts all those pieces together:

```cpp
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    [[maybe_unused]] ComInit com_library {};

    IDesktopWallpaperPtr spWallpaper {};
    CheckError(spWallpaper.CreateInstance(CLSID_DesktopWallpaper));

    auto const count { ::GetMonitorDevicePathCount(spWallpaper) };
    std::wcout << std::format(L"Monitor count: {}\n", count);

    for (uint32_t index {}; index < count; ++index)
    {
        auto const dev_path { ::GetMonitorDevicePathAt(spWallpaper, index) };
        auto const wallpaper { ::GetWallpaper(spWallpaper, dev_path) };

        std::wcout << std::format(L"\t{}: \"{}\" - \"{}\"\n", index, dev_path, wallpaper);
    }
}
```

The code starts out by initializing the COM library, followed by construction of a COM object identified by `CLSID_DesktopWalllpaper`. The order is crucial, so that `ComInit`'s d'tor runs *after* `spWallpaper`'s.

The remainder is pretty much straight forward: Query for the number of monitor devices, retrieve the device path for each in turn, and get the wallpaper associated with it. Output formatting is done using C++20's [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) library. This currently (VS 2022 Preview 4.1) requires compiling with the [`/std:c++latest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version) compiler option.