# Not sure how to use IDesktopWallpaper

Tags: winapi, rust, windows-rs

In the documentation there is a struct 'IDesktopWallpaper' with a method named 'GetWallpaper'. The method takes a reference to 'self' but there is no constructor method for 'IDesktopWallpaper'.

```
use windows::{
    core::*,
    Win32::UI::Shell::IDesktopWallpaper,
};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    unsafe {
        //                              ?????
        IDesktopWallpaper::GetWallpaper(&self, monitorid);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

What am I supposed to do in order to get my desired outcome?

Comment: All COM methods have a hidden self/this parameter. This makes this a generic question about COM...

Comment: @Anders Could you point me in the right direction? I'm having trouble making sense of the documentation.

Comment: I don't use rust. Find a guide about using COM in rust...

Comment: I'd posted a full example to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69501315/1889329) previously, in C++, that retrieves the wallpaper for multiple monitors. If you're still struggling, I'll translate it into Rust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

COM generally uses factory methods to construct COM objects. The "standard" factory method for classic COM is [`CoCreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance). It needs a class ID that identifies the specific implementation (in case there are multiple) and an interface ID that names the requested interface.

The [windows](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate exposes class IDs differently from the Windows SDK: The latter frequently uses `CLSID_`-prefixes, wheres the former doesn't. `DesktopWallpaper` in the windows crate is the same GUID as `CLSID_DesktopWallpaper` in the Windows SDK.

Another difference is that [`CoCreateInstance`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/Com/fn.CoCreateInstance.html) in the windows crate is generic over its returned interface type (as opposed to taking the address of a type-erased `void*` in the Windows SDK). Clients will need to explicitly name the interface type they are requesting.

The following code initializes COM (required), instantiates a COM object, and returns an `IDesktopWallpaper` interface for further use:

```rust
use windows::{
    core::Result,
    Win32::{
        System::Com::{CoCreateInstance, CoInitialize, CLSCTX_ALL},
        UI::Shell::{DesktopWallpaper, IDesktopWallpaper},
    },
};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    // Initialize COM
    unsafe { CoInitialize(None) }?;
    // Create a DesktkopWallpaper object and return its IDesktopWallpaper interface
    let wallpaper: IDesktopWallpaper =
        unsafe { CoCreateInstance(&DesktopWallpaper, None, CLSCTX_ALL) }?;
    // Use the COM object
    unsafe { wallpaper.GetWallpaper(...) };

    Ok(())
}
```

You'll need to have the following in your *Cargo.toml* file:

```ini
[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.42.0"
features = [
    "Win32_UI_Shell",
    "Win32_System_Com",
]
```